# TTypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'", 'occurred at index FFT Peak (Hz)')

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have reset the indexed already. My FFT peak

```
0.12667
0.12
0.11667
0.10333
0.1
0.096667
0.093333
0.09
0.09
0.09
0.086667
0.086667
0.083333
0.083333
0.083333
0.076667
0.076667
0.073333
0.073333
0.073333
0.07
0.07
0.07
0.07
0.066667
0.066667
0.063333
0.06
0.06
0.056667
0.056667
0.056667
0.056667
0.056667
0.053333
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.046667
0.046667
0.046667
0.046667
0.043333
0.043333
0.043333
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
0.04
```

Its is one of the column in dataframe.
and i am trying to find outliers in it before applying classifier

here is my function to find outlier

```
def outliers(x): 
   return np.abs(x- x.median()) > 1.5*(x.quantile(.75)-x.quantile(0.25))


def replace(x):  
   out = x[outliers(x)]
   return x.replace(to_replace = [out.min(),out.max()], 
                    value = [np.percentile(x,5),np.percentile(x,95)])

X1o = X3_a.apply(replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your column to a float object before `apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
X1o = pd.to_numeric(X3_a, errors='coerce').apply(replace)
```